# Integrationtest IHost TestServer won't shutdown

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit

I wrote some integration tests for an aspnetcore 3.1 application using xunit.
Tests show successful, but process is still running. After some time I get:

> The process dotnet:1234 has finished running tests assigned to it, but is still running. Possible reasons are incorrect asynchronous code or lengthy test resource disposal [...]

This behavior does even show with boilerplate code like:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestServer()
        {
            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
                {
                    // Add TestServer
                    webHost.UseTestServer();
                    webHost.Configure(app => app.Run(async ctx =>
                        await ctx.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!")));
                    
                });

            // Build and start the IHost
            var host = await hostBuilder.StartAsync();
        }
```

Same if I add await host.StopAsync()...

I am on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to dispose the host at the end of the test. Most likely, the error is caused just because you don't dispose disposable resource.
2. I would recommend you to use WebApplicationFactory for testing instead of HostBuilder. You may find more in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Wow, this was easy, disposing host worked ;) Thanks! 
I will look into WebApplicationFactory.

Comment: Disposing worked for me too. I'm using XUnit tests so I made a fixture/collection and made any tests that depended on the server running use the collection. The collection disposes of the server at the end.

Comment: `Dispose()` on `TestServer` instance worked also for me, I was looking for `StopAsync()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Since i was working with NUnit the suggested change was not an option (it is based on xunit). So i was digging into it and the root cause of it was quite simple:
I created a long running task in the Startup.cs which was doing some monitoring throughout all the hosting's lifetime. So i had to stop this task, and then also the instance of the TestHost was disposed properly.